# Drive through Germany and Switzerland with barbells as luggage

Tags: luggage, germany, automobiles, switzerland

I need to pass through Germany and Switzerland. I want to take barbells with me, but the only way they stick to my car was that way:

[image]

I will be the only passenger and the barbell will be wrapped , and there will be much more other luggage which will prevent barbell from swinging. However, I wonder if I break any traffic laws in given countries, because I use the place between passenger sits as luggage store or similar.

Comment: @pnuts back sits already folded, and it was the only way it could pass, I've tried many configurations.

Comment: @pnuts it might be, but it would then press agaist the door and press against the rear window, which I thought to cause even more potential problems

Comment: What about tying them to the roof? If you have luggage rails, you can easily wrap them in plastic and tie them to one side with a couple of straps, or do it diagonally. They look like they will not protrude, so that should be a safe and legal option.

Answer (score 8):

Being familiar with German traffic laws as a driver and given that barbells are not illegal or anything else, the only constraint imposed upon you by the law and regulations is that your luggage be **safely stored**! Safely stored as in does not pose a threat to you or other people even in case of an accident and it should not impede your ability to operate the vehicle. That includes not obstructing your sight through the mirrors and of course your vehicle should not be overloaded either.
Here is [a great instructional video of German automobile club ADAC that gets the message across even if you don't understand German](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WA0JnHMVNQ). The big umbrella in the video could be compared to the barbell I guess. (There are some tips on how to safely store your stuff on [this related page](https://www.adac.de/infotestrat/adac-im-einsatz/motorwelt/ladungssicherung.aspx), in German, [or here for skies](http://www.tagesspiegel.de/mobil/skier-und-koffer-im-auto-richtig-sichern-toedliches-gepaeck/9208438.html), again in German.)

E.g. the barbell should not be able to slide through the front windshield if you were to brake heavily. Judging from your picture you are good on that one.

Safe and overloaded to some extent are judgemental calls, with the ultimate call given to a police officer should they decide to stop you. That being said, if you use a handful of common sense you should be fine.

Comment: Maybe it should be another question, if the rear window is allowed to be covered by the luggage. It's a typical view on Polish roads in holiday season.

Comment: @GeoLog81 please see my updated answer. About the rear window, if you should run into that problem that would merit a new question. Personally I always leave at least a channel of sight for the rear view mirror.

Comment: @GeoLog81 To the best of my knowledge, if the rear window is covered so you cannot use the inside rear mirror, you *must* be able to use outside rear view mirrors on both sides of the car. But if you can, you should again be fine. Caveat: IANAL.